# Alternative to __asm _emit on 64-bit Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, inline-assembly

***EDIT:*** Previous one got marked as duplicate. It's one thing to write a function in assembly with a prologue and epilogue then call it and another thing to straight up incorporate assembly code trough bytes into any other piece of code, which is what I want to do.

---

I need an alternative to __asm _emit more specifically, on 64-bit Visual Studio, as inline assembly is available on 32-bit but right before they started writing the 64-bit version they decided they do not condone the use of inline assembly.

I need the ability of incorporating assembly code straight into my functions using bytes. So that, the following code would print 69 first, then 0.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int _eax;

    __asm
    {
        mov eax, 69;
        mov _eax, eax;
    }
    printf("%d\n", _eax); // 69

    // 0x31, 0xC0
    // xor eax, eax
    __asm _emit 0x31;
    __asm _emit 0xC0;

    __asm
    {
        mov _eax, eax;
    }

    printf("%d\n", _eax); // 0
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are special compiler intrinsics for specific opcodes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/x86-intrinsics-list?view=vs-2019

Comment: Write your function in assembly?

Comment: I do not want prologues and epilogues. I do not want functions, I want plain instructions incorporated straight into whatever function I want. For example, I create a macro with the __asm _emits that form a xor eax, eax instruction, then wherever I pop that macro it will do just that without having to make a call into another function or add any other instructions automatically

Comment: Then use a different compiler, for example ICC or clang for MSVC-style asm-blocks syntax, or ICC, clang, or gcc for GNU C inline asm (very different syntax, more control over hat the compiler does around your code).  You literally can't get what you want with MSVC.  However it's not useful or sane to just randomly scatter asm instructions between C++ statements and assume that compiler-generated instructions aren't going to step on your toes.

Comment: What you want is impossible. VC++ as you noticed does not support inline assembly in 64-bit mode at all.

Comment: MS has **definitely** removed inline assembly from 64bit compiles, supposedly due to the complex parameter handling and other optimizations. So you have no other choice than use assembly. For 32 bits compilings you can use the function attribute `__naked` that creates a 'bare' function without epilogue and prologue, and where you can insert inline assembly.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate of your first question because it's still the same question.  Re-asking isn't going to change the facts.  Could be reopened If you can show a safe / sane example use-case for MSVC-style inline asm that can't be done better with pure C, then we can give you more definite answers about what you could do with MSVC or with a different compiler.  (Not this; it uses `emit` to modify a register without telling the compiler about it, which I don't think is safe even for MSVC.  Also there's no point in using a `mov` to a local var with a regular `_asm{}` block.)